Can I perform cross-database queries in LinqPad with postgres databases
I'm using postgresql driver in linqpad to connect to my databases.
I've a need to access more than one such database in a C# script to perform a bunch of database updates.
Is it possible in linqpad to access multiple database in 1 c# script, e.g.:
var users = db_connection1.Users.Where(...);
var employees = db_connection2.Employees.Where(...);



Don't use Postgresql but I presume you are using EF Core which supports PostgreSql and if so then the answer is probably - It Depends. If you are building the DataContext using your own assembly for either of the databases, then yes. Otherwise if the database structures are exactly the same then you can create another connection using var db2 = new TypedData(connectionString); . But if not then AFAIK the answer is no.
